# Es correcto utilizar este codigo para calcular un numero aproximado en base a la entrada de un error absoluto?

Tags: python, matemáticas

Hola soy nuevo en este mundillo , y estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta. Pero me he trabado en este ejercicio, ya que no tengo a nadie para consultar les dejo el codigo.-Estoy haciendo en Python 3.8-
Creo que el punto a esta correcto mi problema es con el d, cualquier sugerencia es valorada. Muchas Gracias.

```
# El número 1 pi/4 se puede aproximar de la siguiente manera:

# pi/4 = 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 - 1/11 + 1/13 - 1/15 ... 

# a) Escribir un programa que le pregunte al usuario la cantidad de términos a sumar y que muestre la aproximación de pi con esa cantidad de términos.
# d) Modificar el programa para que en lugar de pedir la cantidad de términos a sumar, pida al usuario un número decimal epsilon (muy chico) y calcule la suma hasta que el error comparado con el valor de la calculadora sea menor que epsilon

# Aca empieza el del error...

# d:

# Error = Valor Aproximado - Valor Verdadero

import math
n = 0.01
# Segunda forma con ciclo while:
print("Con while: ")
suma = 0
ERROR = suma - math.pi
print(ERROR)
i = 1
while(i<=1000):
  ERROR = suma- math.pi
  if ERROR < 0:
    ERROR = ERROR * (-1)
  if ERROR > n:
    signo = (-1)**(i+1)
    suma = suma + ( 1/(2*i-1) )*signo
  i = i + 1
print("El valor de pi con un error de", n, ":", suma*4)
```

Mi problema es si esto esta bien que pase, (me parece raro..):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para 3 valores de n(error) da el mismo resultado:
(ignorar el -3,14... xD)
Trate de hacerlo lo mas detallado posible

Comment: De primeras el código parece correcto. ¿Qué problemas te da? ¿Te sale algún error? ¿Se te queda clavado?

Comment: Mi duda es acerca de que por ejemplo si coloco

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios errores en el código. El primero y más grave es el cálculo del error:

```
ERROR = suma- math.pi
```

Debería ser `suma - math.pi/4` ya que el valor que estás aproximando mediante la suma de fracciones es pi/4 y no pi.

Tal como lo tenías el error siempre va a ser mayor y por tanto el bucle se repetirá el máximo número de veces (1001) por lo que te dará siempre el mismo resultado.

Con esta corrección ya verás que te sale un valor distinto para la aproximación de pi según el error que pongas. Pero sigue habiendo un par de cosas mal:

1. No sales nunca del bucle `while` hasta que no se haya repetido 1001 veces. Aún si el valor aproximado de pi lo has alcanzado en la iteración 28, por ejemplo, el bucle seguirá repitiéndose 1001 veces (aunque a partir de la iteración 28 ya no se actualizará más la aproximación). Eso es un desperdicio de CPU. Deberías abandonar el bucle tan pronto como detectes que el error está dentro de lo admisible (por ejemplo con un `break`).
2. Este es más filosófico. El programa intenta encontrar un valor aproximado para pi, por lo que hay que suponer que **no sabemos el verdadero valor de pi**. Por tanto es hacer trampa el usar `math.pi` para encontrar el error (aunque el enunciado te dice que compares con el valor de la calculadora, por lo que en realidad te está pidiendo que hagas esa trampa).

Respecto a esto último ¿cómo podríamos hacer entonces para saber el error? La respuesta es que en vez de comparar con el valor real de pi (que es desconocido), comparamos con la aproximación obtenida en la iteración anterior del bucle. Ya que en cada iteración la fracción que añadimos (o quitamos) es menor, cuando esa fracción (multiplicada por 4) sea menor que el error solicitado, podremos dejar de iterar.

Usando esta idea:

```
n = float(input("Error deseado? "))
# Segunda forma con ciclo while:
suma = 0
i = 1
while True:              # Bucle "infinito" del que se sale con break
  termino = 1/(2*i-1)
  signo = (-1)**(i+1)
  suma += termino*signo
  if termino*4 < n:
    break
  i = i + 1
print("El valor de pi con un error de", n, ":", suma*4, "tras", i-1, "iteraciones")
```

Ejemplos de ejecución:

```
Error deseado? 0.1
El valor de pi con un error de 0.1 : 3.189184782277596 tras 20 iteraciones

Error deseado? 0.01
El valor de pi con un error de 0.01 : 3.1465677471829556 tras 200 iteraciones

Error deseado? 0.0001
El valor de pi con un error de 0.0001 : 3.1416426510898874 tras 20000 iteraciones
```

## Notas

En un comentario Chema Cortés observa:

> En realidad, no puedes asegurar que un término del sumatorio sea inferior en valor absoluto a la suma del resto de términos del sumatorio.

Esto en general sería correcto, pero no en este caso en particular. Esta aproximación de Pi proviene en realidad del desarrollo en [serie de Taylor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serie_de_Taylor) de la función arcotangente `atan(x)`. Según ese desarrollo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La función es válida para x entre 0 y 1. Naturalmente la serie es infinita por lo que nunca podemos terminar de calcularla. Si calculamos sólo hasta un término *n*, la suma de todos los infinitos términos que aún quedan sin calcular son lo que se llama el *resto* (o el error).

Podemos escribir por tanto la fórmula anterior como un sumatorio que sume sólo los *n* primeros términos, y le añadimos un error "desconocido" *E<sub>n</sub>* que lógicamente dependerá de hasta dónde hayamos llegado con el sumatorio (*n*):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ocurre que [se puede demostrar](http://www.stumblingrobot.com/2015/12/21/prove-an-inequality-for-the-error-of-the-taylor-polynomial-of-arctan-x/) que ese resto *E<sub>n</sub>* está acotado según la siguiente fórmula:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya tenemos la base matemática necesaria para explicar nuestro caso. Basta hacer *x=1* en la fórmula del sumatorio.

En el lado izquierdo queda `arctan(1)` y sabemos que el ángulo cuya tangente es 1 es el de 45º, o sea pi/4. En el lado derecho queda justamente la suma de fracciones que estábamos usando para estimar el valor de pi/4, tras sumar los *n* primeros términos de la serie, más un error *E*, que será lo que nos queda para llegar al valor exacto de pi/4.

Según la cota demostrada, ese error sería menor que (haciendo *x=1*) 1/(2_n_+1), es decir, justamente el valor del término *n*-ésimo en el cual habíamos detenido el sumatorio.

Por tanto es válido el enfoque propuesto en el código. Si paramos cuando el término a sumar es menor que el error solicitado, podemos asegurar que nos hemos acercado lo suficiente a pi/4 (ya que la suma de los infinitos términos restantes va a ser menor a ese término n-ésimo).

**Nota adicional**. Todo esto tiene poco interés práctico, ya que esta aproximación de pi en particular es una de las más lentas que se pueden hacer. Ya has visto que para llegar a un error de 0.0001 (es decir, hemos sacado con exactitud sólo tres decimales de pi), son necesarias 20000 iteraciones del bucle.

Comment: En realidad, no puedes asegurar que un término del sumatorio sea inferior en valor absoluto a la suma del resto de términos del sumatorio. Únicamente puedes hablar de error si conoces el valor exacto de Pi a través de algún otro medio.

Comment: Muchas Gracias @abulafia por tomarte el tiempo de responder con tanto detalle, me ayudo mucho sobretodo la parte filosofica que mencionas. Saludos!! :)

Comment: @ChemaCortes Gracias a vos tambien por responder, es verdad no se conoce el valor exacto de pi. Lo tendre en cuenta la proxima vez :)

Comment: @ChemaCortes No me cabe la réplica en un comentario :-) He ampliado mi respuesta.

Comment: Estupenda réplica. Aún así, si sumas los términos por parejas (positivo+negativo), puedes delimitar el error al promedio de la suma, con lo que se necesitan menos iteraciones para alcanzar el error solicitado.

Answer (score 1):

Esta respuesta es para completar un poco la que ha puesto @abulafia.

Como los términos del sumatorio van alternando el signo, tendremos mejor acotado el error si sumamos por parejas, necesitando menos términos del sumatorio para alcanzar un error dado.

Aprovecho para poner una versión *iterable* del algoritmo:

```py
from itertools import count, takewhile, cycle

error = float(input("Error deseado? "))

# Términos del sumatorio (sin signo)
terminos = (1/(2*k -1) for k in count(1))

# Tomamos los términos menores de error/2
it = takewhile(lambda x: 2*x >= error, terminos)

# Tomamos pares
ts = list(x-y for x,y in zip(it, it))

# Sumatorio
pi = 4 * sum(ts)

print(f"El valor de pi con un error de {error} : {pi} tras {2*len(ts)} términos")
```

Los resultados:

```
El valor de pi con un error de 0.1 : 3.0418396189294024 tras 10 términos

El valor de pi con un error de 0.01 : 3.1315929035585524 tras 100 términos

El valor de pi con un error de 0.0001 : 3.1414926535900367 tras 10000 términos
```